# Unpacking multiple lists and dictionaries as function arguments in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

[Possible Relevant Questions](https://www.google.com/search?ei=j3vSW_GOGKjujwSB65h4&q=unpacking+function+arguments+in+python+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=unpacking+function+arguments+in+python+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6012.7928..8152...0.0..0.63.954.17......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.SjA92gobDgA) (I searched for the same question and couldn't find it)

---

Python makes a convenient way to unpack arguments into functions using an asterisk, as explained in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

```
>>> list(range(3, 6))            # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> list(range(*args))            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

In my code, I'm calling a function like this:

```
def func(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

In Python 3, I call it like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]

func(*a, *b, *c)
```

Which outputs

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

In Python 2, however, I encounter an exception:

```
>>> func(*a, *b, *c)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    func(*a, *b, *c)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

It seems like Python 2 can't handle unpacking multiple lists. Is there a better and cleaner way to do this than

```
func(a[0], a[1], a[2], b[0], b[1], b[2], ...)
```

My first thought was I could concatenate the lists into one list and unpack it, but I was wondering if there was a better solution (or something that I don't understand).

```
d = a + b + c
func(*d)
```

Comment: You don't actually need `d` to hold the concatenated list; you can write `f(*a+b+c)` directly.  The only downside I see to this approach is that it doesn't work with arbitrary iterables, they all have to be actual lists (or all tuples).  `f(*itertools.chain(a, b, c))` could fix that if needed.

Comment: Unless you're maintaining an ancient python library you should just use Python 3.

Comment: Long story short, the program has to be compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I need to be able to do this in python 2 today as well. I am going to create a bounty.

Comment: python2 is not supported anymore, and should NOT BE USED

Comment: @KetZoomer I understand. I have 30k+ rep answering questions about python 3 for the last 6 years and I am telling you that in this case, it is impossible for me not to use it. Too bad.

Comment: Do you still need an answer, or the given answer solves your purpose?

Comment: Jason's answer sufficed for me, but of course now I am no longer working on the project as Python 2 is officially unsupported.

Answer (score 13):

Recommendation: Migrate to Python 3
*As of January 1, 2020, the 2.x branch of the Python programming language is no longer supported by the Python Software Foundation.*

## Unpacking Lists and passing to `*args`

#### Python 3 Solution

```py
def func(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]

func(*a, *b, *c)
```

#### Python 2 Solution

If Python 2 is required, then `itertools.chain` will provide a workaround:

```py
import itertools


def func(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]

func(*itertools.chain(a, b, c))
```

#### Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

## Unpacking Dictionaries and passing to `**kwargs`

#### Python 3 Solution

```py
def func(**args):
    for k, v in args.items():
        print(f"key: {k}, value: {v}")


a = {"1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three"}
b = {"4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six"}
c = {"7": "seven", "8": "eight", "9": "nine"}

func(**a, **b, **c)
```

#### Python 2 Solution

As [Elliot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074293/elliot) mentioned in the comments, if you need to unpack multiple dictionaries and pass to `kwargs`, you can use the below:

```py
import itertools

def func(**args):
    for k, v in args.items():
        print("key: {0}, value: {1}".format(k, v))


a = {"1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three"}
b = {"4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six"}
c = {"7": "seven", "8": "eight", "9": "nine"}

func(**dict(itertools.chain(a.items(), b.items(), c.items())))
```

Comment: Perfect. Can you also provide a python 2 equivalent for unpacking a dictionary, by any chance?

Comment: `func(**dict(itertools.chain(a.items(), b.items(), c.items())))` (if a, b, and c are dicts)